# How to build Hadoop(1.0.4) libhfs on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, libssl, libcrypto

I am trying to build libhdfs on Ubunutu 12.04 for [mountable hdfs](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS) and I was stuck at the first step
1. in HADOOP_HOME: ant compile-c++-libhdfs -Dlibhdfs=1
In this step it will configure and make utils and pipes, but when it configure pipes it always failed on
checking for HMAC_Init in -lssl... no
I found this function is now in libcrypto in ubuntu 12.04, so I modify configure to ignore this check and add -lcrypto option, this will work when I manually configure and make pipes
But when I use the ant again, it will regenerate configure and failed again...
Is there any method to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2127

Just edit ${HADOOP_INSTALL}/src/c++/utils/m4/hadoop_utils.m4, at line 54 & 55

```
-AC_CHECK_LIB([ssl], [HMAC_Init], [], <br>
-  AC_MSG_ERROR(Cannot find libssl.so, please check))<br>
+AC_CHECK_LIB([crypto], [HMAC_Init], [], <br>
+  AC_MSG_ERROR(Cannot find libcrypto.so, please check))<br>
```

I don't know why it stat as fixed but not actually fix in release...